# ASP.Net: SQL Insert query not being called

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a webpage uses ADO.Net that calls a stored procedure and passes variables to insert an item. Within the webserver, this works, however within the production server it is not working. Is there anyway to look at the SQL Server and see if it is returning an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep investigation, it was an error on my part and the user. Apologies for the vagueness

Answer (score 1):

What does "is not working" mean? How do you know that the ASP.Net code is calling anything? Is it possible that the connection string is pointing to the wrong place? Don't you have the ability to put try / catch in the code that calls the stored procedure, and output or log any errors? I would tell you to run profiler or check the SQL Server error log, but I'm not convinced your code is connecting to a server at all, never mind the right one. The place to start debugging this is in your app, not in SQL Server. Verify that you're connecting to the right database and that you are actually entering the code that is calling the stored procedure. If it's still "not working" then you need to narrow down what that means. Either it works or you'll get an error message (unless you just have an empty catch{} handler).

Comment: +1 for being spot on with all of the points but you could have expressed it a bit more calmly

Comment: @Tahbaza Calmly? What are you talking about? Did I yell, curse, what?

Comment: Ok my ap is calling the correct database, because it is making select calls to the correct database. This is in a try catch. and I know its getting past it because I set a label caption to a certain text and just returned the code right after so it is going to it, but this is the only sp that is not being called within this page.

Comment: If you use SQL Profiler then you will be able to see what is being passed to your DB. You'll be able to check you're passing the right values then, and you can get the call so you can test it directly. I always find this technique yields results as it highlights errors pretty efficiently.